# Expand or shrink striped array in Windows?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, window, software-raid, raid-0

I plan to replace 2 of my HDDs (let's call them A & B, they're not in RAID) with 2 larger HDDs (C & D) in software RAID 0 (Striped volume in Windows). The one problem I have is that my case does not have any free 3,5" bays. I could let the 2 drives hang out of the side of the case for several days in a pinch, but I'd rather avoid doing that. The solution that came to mind is:

1. Replace old drive A with new drive C
2. Create a simple NTFS volume **at the end of** drive C with space enough to hold the contents of old drives A & B
3. Copy all the contests of old drive A to the new volume
4. Replace old drive A with old drive B
5. Copy the contents of old drive B to the new volume
6. Replace old drive B with new drive D
7. Create a striped NTFS volume across drives C & D equal in size to the free space on drive C
8. Move the files from the temporary simple volume to the new striped volume
9. Delete the temporary volume
10. Extend the striped volume to fill the entirety of drives C & D

That sounds like it should work, but I've never used Windows striped volumes before, so I don't know if I'll be able to extend it after deleting the temporary simple volume.

P.S. yes, I am prepared to deal with the increased likelihood of losing all data on the striped volume in the event of drive failure.

Comment: Doesn't your first step: "Replace old drive A with new drive C" cause your array to immediately fail?

Comment: @BlindSpots striped volume doesn't get created until step 7, when both old drives are out and both new drives are in.

Comment: Does that mean you do currently have a striped volume?  If so, I misunderstood and thought you were upgrading an existing array to one larger.  I understand you are not concerned about the array becoming inconsistent, but for interest sake what is the reason for doing this, especially with your system volume.

Comment: @BlindSpots no RAID at the moment, so no problems with switching out old drives one at a time. I should have included this information in my blog post in the first place. I like to have a lot of space and everything in its place, so the larger capacity of a striped volume is appealing, as is the extra speed. The data is not irreplaceable, so I don't mind losing it. I may add a mirrored volume at the end to hold more valuable data, as well as short stroke the striped volume a bit.

Comment: If you want to test it just setup a VM with some virutalization software and try what you're going to do in that enviornment without jeopardyzing your live data. Using small volumes would be enough and you could also get an idea about how your OS handles it.

Comment: @Seth good idea, I'll have to do that if I don't get an answer.

Comment: I don't see any reason why it would not work.  I question why you would want to.   Is it for video?  Gaming?  Read speed?  Write speed?  You could annihilate the possible performance improvement simply by switching to solid state.  Can't imagine you need more than 2 TB of fast storage.  Your questions and your operating environment incline me to think you might want to revisit the underlying reason(s) for doing it or at least entertain other approaches.

Comment: @BlindSpots the space I'm looking for vastly exceeds 2TB. My boot drive is already an SSD, I just want a lot of space to store files that I could live with losing.

Comment: If it isn't performance then why bother?  You are increasing complexity and and risk, decreasing flexibility, without increasing disk capacity

Comment: @BlindSpots I don't not want performance, I just want capacity a lot more, to the point where SSD storage becomes prohibitively expensive.

Comment: I agree HDD fits your need for capacity over SSD.  I originally suggested SSD as I falsely assumed you were chasing a perceived performance gain.  I am now making a different case that stripping (RAID 0) HDD storage is decreasing reliability, increasing complexity, but gaining NO capacity over simply using them non-RAID. If your goal is to see the 2 x HDD as a single drive you can have a single volume span the two drives.  Historically, all my RAID pain has been related to using RAID 0/1 on Windows workstations, unrelated to any actual drive failures.

Comment: @BlindSpots how much more reliable is a spanned volume compared to a striped one? I expect losing the drive that holds the start of the filesystem in a spanned volume would wipe everything, and losing the drive that holds the end of the filesystem would at best wipe every file that has any fragments on the second volume.

Comment: It is orders of magnitude more reliable than striping, where a drive loss is a total data loss, but it would be a major PIA to get back up.  Spanned volume doesn't fragment files between drives.  It completely fills the first drive then  fills the second.  A full failure of a drive would take the volume down.  Files would still exist on both drives but you'd need to use an NTFS drive scanner to enumerate the files and restore them to a new location (similar to recovering recently deleted data.  So stripe=total loss, span=major pia.  Scratch that, don't stripe, don't span.  Answer coming :-)

Comment: Answered.  I based my answer on your question and comments and really appreciate your willingness to clarify.  I am not anti-RAID and have current and past experience with hw and sw RAID on all sorts of Windows/Linux  servers and workstations, as well as appliances (Synology, FreeNAS/TrueNAS, Unitrends). Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No, it is not possible to resize striped or mirrored volumes on dynamic disks in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

---

### Skip RAID, Instead Mount as Folder

---

Based on the additional info you provided, my recommended solution is to **mount the second hard disk drive as a folder** in whatever path you choose on the first hard disk drive.

I am using the following assumptions:

- **Performance** is a benefit, but **not critical**
- **Reliability** is a benefit, but **not critical**
- Maximizing **capacity is a goal**
- Using **2 HDD as 1** larger HDD **is a goal**

---

#### Mount HDD as Folder <sup>1</sup>  *(Recommended)*

---

**Pros:**

- Available capacity is maximized
- Capacity of both drives is accessible from one drive
- Drives have their own MFTs
- Drives can be mounted normally on any system
- Data reliability is normal, data on one HDD is not dependent on the other HDD
- Performance is normal, each HDD is independent
- Data recovery is typical

**Cons:**

- Is not a contiguous volume *(if a con)*
- At some point data in one of the drives may exceed that drive's capacity  <sup>2</sup>

---

#### RAID 0 *(Not Recommended)*

---

**Pros:**

- Available capacity is maximized
- Capacity of both drives is accessible from one drive
- Performance can be better, especially read operations
- Contiguous volume

**Cons:**

- Drives can't be individually mounted normally on any system
- Data reliability is worse as all data is split between dependent HDDs
- Data recovery is extremely difficult, when possible, and requires specialized tools/knowledge.
- At some point data in one of the drives may exceed that drive's capacity  <sup>3</sup>

---

#### Windows Spanned Volume *(Not Recommended)*

---

**Pros:**

- Available capacity is maximized
- Capacity of both drives is accessible from one drive
- Performance is typically close to normal afaik
- Data reliability is near normal as it is not split between HDDs  <sup>4</sup>
- Contiguous volume

**Cons:**

- Drives cannot be individually mounted normally on any system
- Failure of either HDD means failure of volume
- Data recovery is atypical. In particular healthy HDDs in a failed volume require time consuming and complex recovery compared to the recommended solution
- At some point data in one of the drives may exceed that drive's capacity  <sup>3</sup>

---

#### Footnotes

---

<sup>1</sup> *Some links*
*[Windows Central: how-mount-hard-drive-folder-windows-10](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-mount-hard-drive-folder-windows-10)*
*[Make Use Of: windows-11-mount-drive-folder](https://www.makeuseof.com/windows-11-mount-drive-folder/)*

<sup>2</sup> *With or without the 2 drive limitation, migrating to one or more larger drives would be incredibly easy in this case*  One could simply image the data to a new drive, or add another drive and mount it as a folder somewhere in the root drive's path.

<sup>3</sup> *In both the Spanned drive and RAID0 migrating to one or more larger drives would be very challenging and involve a full backup of the volume, recreating the dynaic drive or array on new hardware and then copying back all the data*

<sup>4</sup> *While I characterize data reliability in (spanned volume) as 'near normal' and a 'pro', the point really needs clarification.  While the failure of HD1 (in a volume that spans 2 or more HDDs) will not affect the data on HDD2 (or HDD3,...,HDDx), and while the Windows spanning (afaik) stores the files in their entirety on a single drive, recovering data from the healthy drives is time consuming because of the absence of a healthy volume (MFT). It is a similar process to recovering data from a failed drive with damaged MFT and/or bad sectors, with better results.
So, this may be a useful pro when comparing spanning to RAID0 with a HDD failure, however any benefit is quickly eclipsed when comparing to the recommended solution where a hdd1 failure would leave the data on HDD2 (and HDD3,...,HDDx) intact (like spanned volumes) but the data would also be immediately, quickly, and easily accessible.  Undamaged data? Perhaps.  Accessible? Eventually.*

Comment: I have a hunch that the filesystem is an independent layer above the volume abstraction layer, and so will fragment files as it sees fit across spanned volume drives. I also like to have deep descriptive directory structures, and if I do independent drives, I'll eventually encounter a situation where I have to break the structure or move TB+ directories around, and that's assuming one of the root dirs doesn't grow beyond the capacity of a single drive. For the small amount of data I mustn't lose, I'll happily make a mirrored volume at the end of the drives, and get better reliability.

Comment: I can't speak to your hunch and I have tried to verify what I can but there is not a dearth of clear information on how this is managed in Windows.  I also do not recommend spanning.  Your requirement for 'mustn't lose data' is newly added but is not addressed by RAID1 as you suggest but by proper backups.  This is a common misconception about RAID1.

Comment: I have mentioned that I'll use a mirrored volume for files which I can't tolerate losing in the event of a single drive failure in an earlier comment. You're correct about offsite backups for irreplaceable files, but that part wasn't going to fit into the 600 character limit, and I hope mostly goes without saying.
I appreciate your well-meaning concern, but for my particular situation, striped volumes are still more attractive than spanned volumes or independent drives.
By the way, there is Linux software that makes Windows striped/spanned volumes work.

Comment: Most of this is noise except  "I'll eventually encounter a situation where I have to break the structure or move TB+ directories around, and that's assuming one of the root dirs doesn't grow beyond the capacity of a single drive. "  I'll update the answer to address that.

Comment: You might indeed need to rearrange data in the future.  That is always the case and not a compelling barrier.  It would mostly appear to be a contiguous volume until you maxed out one of the drives where you would need rearrange some data or upgrade your capacity.  The latter being orders of magnitude easier and faster than RAID0.  You can only fit 2 drives in your system so if there is so much data that you will fill up the two drives, the RAID0 path would require moving all the data off the system and then back on once the new drives were installed and a new array created.

Comment: I only recommending this based on your use case and the things you are noting are important.  I have lots of RAID and don't mind if you have some :-)

Comment: I don't expect to upgrade my bulk storage in the next 5 years, and, if there are no significant breakthroughs in density, until the drives are about to fail, so that's at least 5 years of hassle-free storage* with RAID or a potential annoyance in the back of my mind while working with my bulk storage for 5 years with independent drives. If I must add extra drives (unlikely), I can always add them as independent drives. *Hassle-free unless a drive fails, but losing half the data instead of all data is not going to make a big difference for me.

Comment: I think something was lost in translation.  I was suggesting joining the additional drives together but using a different approach.   You don't need to see either of the additional HHD's as independent drives.  You could mount both as folders inside your C: (system SSD) and for all intents have one drive with access to all the storage.  I agree that you could potentially exceed half your capacity in a single folder but it seemed like the least compelling of all the arguments for/against.  Behaves mostly like you want while retaining the substantial benefits of normal partitions.   Good luck!

Comment: No, I get that completely. The problem isn't just 1 dir growing to more than 100% the drive size. Let's say I have dirs 1 and 2 on drive A. Dirs 1 and 2 are 60% and 40% the size of a single drive's capacity. Now say I want to grow dir 2 to 50%, I'll have to move dir 1 or 2 to drive B, because they will no longer be able to fit on a single drive.

Comment: That is true.  Regardless which direction you go concessions will be made. My weighting is different than yours, but a great deal is subjective.  Best of luck!  Appreciate the discussion.

Comment: Thanks, I enjoyed the discussion as well.